# Asp.net Mvc Routing. "*" meaning in route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

In ASP.NET MVC routing I have seen "*" in routes:

```
{Controller}/{Action},{*parameters}
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We use a Question and Answer format here. It is better to ask your other question as a second question using http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask again, so that the answers can be separate. You could edit your question to take out the other question and post it separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a catchall parameter. It must always be the last, if you want to use one, and it will ignore any slashes `/`. An example:

> Home/Index/Foo/Bar/Baz

`Controller` will be `Home`, `Action` will be `Index` and `parameters` will be `Foo/Bar/Baz`.

If you were using `{Controller}/{Action}/{parameters}` instead, `parameters` would be `Foo` while the rest of the URL would be lost.

Comment: Is it only ignore slashhes?

Comment: I mean it won't see a slash as a separator for parameters anymore. I'll clarify the answer.